# Get ID of container created by docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

We are using Docker compose in our testing pipeline and run multiple tests in parallel (from the same commit, e.g. unit tests + static typing tests + code quality...). A problem is that with one of the tests we need to start the docker-compose service stack and then `exec` in one of the containers.

However, due to the way we are running tests, `docker-compose ps servicename` will return multiple IDs.

What I need is to run `docker-compose up -d` *and* immediately get ID(s) of the service(s) started. Using `docker-compose ps` is not an option.

Is there any way to achieve this? The only way that comes to my mind is using `sed` to replace `container_name` in my `docker-compose.yml` to a deterministic-but-unique name just for the CI tests, but that feels dirty.

Comment: Is the setup something you could do by using a bind-mount `volumes:` directive to inject a config file into the container, or before the service starts in an entrypoint script?  Or can [`docker-compose exec`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/exec/) work for you?

Comment: I don't know how to do it with docker-compose, but maybe you can access from each docker to /proc/self/cgroup and report it. It's not very elegant, but you can get it with a script acceeding to /proc/self/cgroup and execute it as part of entrypoint: `bash -c "<script-to-cgroup>.sh && <your_entrypoint>`

Comment: No need to use sed, just use an env var in the docker compose file, like `"${IMAGE_NAME:-mydefaultcontainername}` and then `IMAGE_NAME=container1 docker-compose up service-name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What worked for my case was using the [magic environment variable](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#compose_project_name) `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME`. When this variable is set and `docker-compose` called, it will "restrict" itself to this project name.

That means that:

```sh
# Start a new stack of containers, overriding their project name (it defaults to the directory name)
$ COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=foobar docker-compose up -d

# This gives empty result
$ docker-compose ps 

# This gives the containers started above
$ COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=foobar docker-compose ps

# This starts a whole new stack, not affecting the output of the commands above
$ COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=second docker-compose up -d 

# This still only returns the services started in the first command
$ COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=foobar docker-compose ps
```

This way I can define the `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` as a slug made up from the commit SHA and stage/test name. That makes the name unique and avoids conflicts.

This has the same effect as using the `-p` parameter of `docker-compose`.